# Cannot connect to any devices on local network

Tags: windows-10, networking, lan, file-sharing, smb

When I try to ping my laptop it shows "Reply from my PC private IP : Destination host unreachable", however there's no problem when I pinging my router.

Previously I was able to access my devices (Local RDC/Ping with CMD/File Sharing) using USB Tethering with my phone

Device that I use right now is Personal Computer (Can't ping/access/connect any devices on LAN), currently connected to LAN with ethernet cable and Laptop for RDC/File sharing connect via Wi-Fi, also router ZTE F609 I got this one from my ISP (probably the problem is from the router itself), I can't access any devices which connect via wireless from ethernet cable.

I've tried many ways to fix this on google, like disable firewall, reset network, re-enable sharing option, turn on SMB 1.0, but none of them work for me

Router IP

```
C:\Users\USER>ping 192.168.1.1 -t
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

Laptop IP

```
C:\Users\USER>ping 192.168.1.4 -t
Pinging 192.168.1.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the commands and output **as text** to the question instead of showing screenshots. Please show details about your network. What devices with what IP addresses do you have? Which address are you trying to `ping` when you get the "unreachable" error? Are you sure the device is currently connected to the network? Do you have router settings to separate the devices from each other? Such separation by the router can also occur when you use a "guest network".

Comment: _(Please don't post screenshots of command-line output - please copy the output and paste it within a code fence in your question/answer.)_ Your router accepts incoming pings/ICMP requests, whereas PCs don't by default and must have a firewall rule created within their OS to allow both the ping and reply _(you'll want to set rules for both `IPv4` [UDP ping] and IPv6 [ICMP `echo-request`/`echo-reply`])_. **SMBv1 _should not_ be enabled on Windows systems** -  disable it asap.

Comment: I think firewall is not the problem, my smartphone can ping the laptop without any problems, and when I connect to LAN with smartphone as mediator (USB Tethering), I can use RDC/File sharing normally. Before SMB 1.0 already disabled, but there's forum says SMB 1.0 needed. Now I have turned it back off